# suggetion for a database design

Tags: database, django-models

I have a scenario and looking for a good database design. My application provide 3 different roles. Admin, Customer, and Narrator.

Customer choose a Narrator and request a service. His request process by Admin to check whether it is valid or not. If it is not valid, Admin will send it back to the Customer with a message. Otherwise, Admin will send the request for the chosen Narrator. The Narrator perform the request and send it back to the Admin. Admin will check it again against some circumstances. If validation fail, Admin send the request back to the Narrator with a message. Otherwise, Admin will mark that request as finished and send it to the Customer.

Here is my basic tables:

- User

  - username
  - password
  - email
- Narrator

  - image
  - rank
  - user_id (FK)
- Customer

  - phone_number
  - address
  - user_id (FK)
- Request

  - customer_id (FK)
  - narrator_id (FK)
  - ...

Actually my problem is how I should design my tables in order to support such a transaction.
I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your text explaining what kind of service you want to deliver is a good lead about what type of models you need. You write about 'admins' and 'messages' but those models are omitted. I also think that  'request' is a property of a `Service`.

Maybe go for more general terms? `Client`, `Supplier`, `Message`, `Service`, `Manager`, `Product`. The `Service` needs a `state` field: `new`, `assigned`, `needs more X`...

Then your story goes as follows:

A `Client` chooses a `Supplier` and sends a `Message` to request a `Service`. A `Service` request is created with the status 'new'. The request will be reviewed by a `Manager`: He sets the state of the `Service` to approved and with that one click also send notification `Message`s to both `Client` and `Supplier`. The `Supplier` will preform the `Service` and on completion change the state... et cetera.

I wonder where `Invoice` comes in and maybe you need to deliver a `Product` in the end.

Comment: In fact, I'm wondering how to implement this request transaction. I mean whether I should create separate tables for `approved request`, `new request`, and `finished request` or just handle it with a `status` field?

Comment: Also If request is not valid how should I mark it and send it back either to `Client` or `Supplier`? Should I handle it within `status field`?

Comment: I think it should reflect the workflow you want to achieve. If it's not to complex a status field can be enough.